# How to trigger the Enter key press event on URL hash modification?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

[**Sandbox here.**](https://codesandbox.io/s/0ooww0zj3n)

I have links organized inside `<li>` elements. On a click event, I change the URL of the page to the corresponding `<div>` id element in the page.

Now, so I am looking for a way to trigger the enter press event in `makeIt()` so that I get a scroll to the related `<div>` element.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
<div>
  <div style="margin-top: 50px;"></div>
  <div style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
    <ul>
      <li
        v-for="i in 3"
        :key="i"
        @click="makeIt(i)"
      >
        Link{{ i }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div
    v-for="i in 3"
    :id="i"
    :class="`div${i}`"
    >
    Div {{ i }}
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  methods: {
    makeIt(hashbang) {
      this.$router.push(`#${hashbang}`)
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.div1 {
    background-color: red;
    height: 600px;
}

.div2 {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 500px;
}

.div3 {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 500px;
}
</style>
```

How to do achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `$event` object from your template and modify your `makeIt` function as;

**HTML**:

```
@click="makeIt(i, $event)"
```

**JS**:

```
makeIt(hashbang, event) {
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
//do something
}
      this.$router.push(`#${hashbang}`)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want to automatically trigger the Enter key press event inside that function

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure that triggering the Enter keypress is the right thing to do in order to scroll down to the desired section.

You might consider handling the scroll with VueScrollTo (you can find it [here](https://github.com/rigor789/vue-scrollto)). Then it would be as easy as calling `VueScrollTo.scrollTo()` from within the `makeIt` method.

```
makeIt(hashbang) {
  this.$router.push(`#${hashbang}`);
  VueScrollTo.scrollTo(`.section-${hashbang}`, 500);
}
```

Here's a working example of how I would do it: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hawz/b3o1yh6e/17/).

Then you might still want to push the index to the route, in order to get to the selected section when browsing to the exact URL.

---

Editing my answer to suggest a different approach:

Since you're using VueRouter, you might take advantage of the **hash** property of routes and the `scrollBehavior()` method when defining the router options. This way you could have something like this:

```
<router-link tag="li" v-for="i in 3" :key="i" :to="{ name: 'theRouteName', hash: '#section-' + i }">Link {{i}}</router-link>
```

This makes the `$router.push()` part and the entire `makeIt()` method unnecessary.

Also, you should add the scroll behavior to the router configuration:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: "history",
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (savedPosition) {˙
      return savedPosition;
    }
    if (to.hash) {
      return { selector: to.hash };
    }
    return { x: 0, y: 0 };
  }
});
```

I saved a version of this solution on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hawz/b3o1yh6e/39/), you might want to try it on your sandbox or your local version of the app.

Comment: If you try it, the scrolling effect will work, but the browser history does not work (when you click back on the browser to the previous hashbang). In Vuetify I can reproduce the scrolling effect too, but the problem is what I mentioned. That is why I want to trigger the Enter key press event because it is the only way to be able to navigate the browser history based on the URL hashbang. Thank you for the feedback though